# running CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE shows error armv7 is deprecated

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, xcode14

I am trying to use cmake to generate xcode project but fail and get error as below, it is said that the cmake project CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE tries to use armv7 architecture but armv7 is deprecated since xcode14 doesn't support armv7, how can I disable CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE compile armv7 architecture?

```
error: The armv7 architecture is deprecated. You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the armv7 architecture. (in target 'cmTC_c124d' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
```